# Will having two antennae at the receiver give better reception?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a 300mbps router with two antennae (tp-link td-wd8968). I'm building a PC and looking for a wireless network card. I have seen seen cards with a single antenna (150mbps) and cards with two antennae (300mbps); I understand the latter is for 802.11n which has higher data rates, but does it have any affect on the signal range?

Comment: [Cross-posted to Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/142152/39511)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, **all other things being equal**, multiple antennas will increase signal range. Primarily by using beamforming they increase signal strength towards the target, which means the signal to noise ratio is strong enough to still send and receive data at a longer distance. It also allows higher throughput at the distances covered by a single antenna, if the max throughput supported by the protocol hasn't been reached yet.

This increase in signal strength works both for sending and receiving.

Keep in mind that this doesn't mean more antennas are always better. It means when all else is equal, and the beamforming is correctly implemented, more antennas are always better.

Beamforming is especially useful for a stationary device (desktop) which only talks with a single other stationary device (access point), because it only ever needs to boost signal strength towards a single direction and suffers no drawbacks from the reduced signal strength in the other directions.

EDIT:

Essentially if you provide a network card with 2 antennas, there are 3 reasonable implementations:

1. Only turn on one antenna, turn off the other one, and scam the customer. (Don't underestimate the likelihood of this possibility)
2. Operate both antennas on 2 different frequencies (resp. spatial streams). This requires having a router with multiple antennas that operate on the same frequencies as the antennas of the network card. This slightly boosts effective range, by increasing the speed from intolerable to tolerable.
3. Operate both antennas on the same frequency. This is always results in beamforming, intentional or not - it's the very definition of beamforming.

You'll want a card that supports 2) and 3), using the former when the signal is strong and the latter when the signal is weak.
Multi-antenna network cards that support 802.11ac are more likely to have a solid beamforming implementation than 802.11n cards, and can collaborate to help each other figure out towards which directions to boost the signal. Nevertheless, 802.11ac is not required for beamforming, and any network card with multiple antennas and a decent beamforming implementation will have better range and throughput than a single antenna network card, even if paired with a 10 year old single antenna router. [Here's an article mentioning beamforming in 802.11n products back in 2009](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2234791/ruckus-introduces-beamforming-for-802-11n.html).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but isn't the beamforming technique a 802.11ac improvement over 802.11a/b/g/n ? Might be useful to add that.

Comment: A standardized collaborative beamforming protocol is in the spec of 802.11ac, which allows multiple ac devices to maximize the benefits of beamforming. Most 802.11n devices with multiple antennae implement their own beamforming protocol, which will provide a benefit even if they are the only device supporting it. Beamforming is older than WiFi.

Answer (score 2):

Really it depend on features supported by wireless chip.

- It can support beamforming, increasing receive and transmit. (I never
  seen it really supported in 802.11n. May be on high-end wireless like Aruba, Ruckus ...)
- It can support diversion, increasing receive sensitivity.
- It can support Spatial streams (MIMO). If both sides has more that 1
  antenna.

Answer (score 1):

Number of antennas doesn't affect your signal range. That's just depending on the transmit power of the radio / antennas. What you get is the higher signal speed due to MIMO capability.

If you have a 802.1n device with one antenna, it can only handle one spatial stream. This gives you (theoretical) max transfer rate of 150Mb/s. Your router is 2x2 MIMO capable, as seems to be the NIC with 2 antennas. They can handle two simultaneous spatial streams thus giving you the 300Mb/s speed.